# Cannot remotely debug JVM via SSH tunnel

Tags: java, debugging, ssh, jvm

I need to debug a Java application using remote debugger via an SSH tunnel. I configured putty on my PC and I'm able to connect to any other service running on the server using tunnel however eclipse remote debugger fails to connect.

On the server side I use Java 1.6.0_21-b06 started with following debug options:

`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8686,server=y,suspend=n`

On my laptop ssh tunnel is configured as:

`L8686 IP_ADDR:8686`

Are there any limitations for JVM debugger when running session over ssh tunnel?

One more thing, when I try to connect, on the server console I can see following log mesage:

`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8686`

Comment: Have you checked all malicious software like firewalls/antiviruses/viruses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same scenario and everything is working fine, here is how I run my java app:

```
 java -Xmx120m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000 -jar bla.jar
```

probably the most relevant part is the -agentlib one.

Comment: this is not recommended for security reasons. only allow local JVM attach and establish a SSH tunnel to the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `L8686 localhost:8686` instead, as the JVM may be refusing connections from non-local addresses? Note that 'localhost' is the address from the server's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

That `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8686` usually occurs if the VM is started or an existing debug session is closed and the VM starts listening for a debug connection again. Maybe running `tcpdump` on the server could give a clue which peer closes the connection and look a bit deeper on that side.