# Unsecured remote debugging is forbidden as threat

Tags: java, eclipse, security, remote-debugging, fortigate

Need to remote debug application on server from my local machine which is in same VPN. App is running on tomcat with param:

agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8011,suspend=n

With using nmap I checked port and its open for communication, after I start debugging in eclipse I get Timeout connection error. When I was speaking with admin on server where tomcat running he told me problem is java.debug.wire.protocol.insecure.configuration*. That means my debugging is flagged as high-security risk and all communication is forbidden.

So I want ask how can I make my communication "secured" to avoid this error and allow me to debug.

*error description:
*This indicates an attempt to use Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP) to access remote debugging.
JDWP allows remote debugging of Java virtual machine. However this protocol does not authenticate users and is insecure. Attackers can use JDWP to do command injection. The JDWP service port should never be exposed to the public.
This signature can detect attempts to exploit a Remote Code Execution Vulnerability in Cisco Prime Data Center Network Manager. A vulnerability in the role-based access control (RBAC) functionality of Cisco Prime Data Center Network Manager (DCNM) could allow an unauthenticated, remote attacker to execute arbitrary code with root privileges on an affected system. The vulnerability is due to a lack of authentication and exposing JDWP service port to the public.*

Comment: Typicall you use an SSH tunnel, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184800/is-it-safe-to-expose-java-remote-debugger-port-to-the-internet

Comment: but on server 22 port is closed, so this solution dont fit my case